# comparison of atmospheric correction methods

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, atmospheric-correction, dark-object-subtraction

I have noticed that dos methods for atmospheric corrections are in the section of radiometric correction `i.*.toar` on GRASS GIS. Does that means that dark object subtraction (DOS) is a method for doing radiometric and atmospheric corrections at once? Input images for that method have to be in DN format I would suspect. I want to compare the results with 6s algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DOS methods are for atmospheric correction only, not radiometric correction.

The i.*.toar modules allow you to combine in one step radiometric correction with some additional DOS atmospheric correction method. The input to the i.*.toar modules is the original DN values.

The default to i.*.toar is "uncorrected", so normally you would use i.*.toar to get a radiometric corrected image, then run that thru i.atcor (which implements 6S) to get your atmospheric correction.

Comment: I have done the 6s but I wasn't sure about DOS. So DOS performing radiometric and atmospheric correction at once?

Comment: No, as I said, DOS methods are atmospheric correction only. But if you are running the i.\*.toar module, then you can choose to do both radiometric correction, and atmospheric correction thru one of the DOS methods.